# Dielectric constants of semiconductors

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, dielectric

If a material has a high dielectric constant, is it a good semiconductor? I am asking this because from what I understand, the dielectric constant in a way measures the materials ability to hold charges. And arent good semiconductors usually those with good carrier charge mobility?

Answer (score 2):

> from what I understand, the dielectric constant in a way measures the materials ability to hold charges.

This is not quite right.

The dielctric constant measures the amount that the bound charges within the material are able to separate, forming microscopic dipoles whose fields counter whatever field you apply to the material.

When used to separate two conductive materials forming a capacitor, the dielectric of the separating material affects the amount of charge the capacitor "holds" at a given potential difference between the "plates". But this charge is actually held on the plates, not on the dielectric.

> And arent good semiconductors usually those with good carrier charge mobility?

This is also a bit off, but also harder to explain. Semiconductors are more related to the number of carriers available in the material than to the mobility of the individual carriers. A material with very few mobile carriers is an insulator. A material with vast numbers of mobile carriers is a metal. A material somewhere in between is a semiconductor. There's quite a bit more to it than that (related to quantum mechanics and the fact that the available carriers in the semiconductor can be affected by temperature, chemical impurities in the material, etc)

It's true that the mobility of the carriers can make certain semiconductors more useful for certain applications, but before that comes into play the material has to be a semiconductor to begin with, and whether it is is defined by other characteristics than the carrier mobility.

It is true that semiconductors tend to have somewhat high dielectric constants, in the range of 11-12 for silicon or gallium arsenide, for example. This is higher than, say, glass (1.5), but it's nowhere near as high as some of the materials used to build very small capacitors, which can range into the 10,000's or 100,000's.